# Unable to run the FIT test using fit runner in java

Tags: java, eclipse, fitnesse

As per the example stated in the following [link](http://realsearchgroup.org/SEMaterials/tutorials/coffee_maker/download/CoffeeMaker_FIT.zip) I tried on running the program.
But my eclipse is throwing an error stated as

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/debug/ui/launcher/JavaLaunchConfigurationTab

Also the Two minitue example montioned at the [Fitnesse.org](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TwoMinuteExample) also not functioning.
It says as 0 test run.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give more details like elaborating on "not functioning". Thanks

Comment: I am trying to install the Fitnesse Plugin in eclipse as per suggestion in the following URL http://www.abodeqa.com/2013/08/15/fitnesse-installation-environment-setup/ it is installing, and I am not able to add the Fitnesse library to the project. as per the link http://testautomationdiary.blogspot.in/2013/01/using-fitnesse-test-tool-for-acceptance.html